# SQL Server : force results for all distinct values in aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

I'm trying to force results to appear for distinct values of a column in my result set. In other words, I'd like any distinct values to show as zero, rather than drop off if they don't have a value in a given group.

For example, my data are roughly as follows:

```
ID      |Quality | Date     | Dollars
-------------------------------------
1       |Good    | 02/28/15 | 1
2       |Better  | 02/28/15 | 2
3       |Best    | 02/28/15 | 3
4       |*Fair*  | 02/28/15 | 1
1       |Good    | 01/31/15 | 1
2       |Better  | 01/31/15 | 2
3       |Best    | 01/31/15 | 3
1       |Good    | 12/31/15 | 1
3       |Best    | 12/31/15 | 3
```

I starred "Fair" to draw attention to it, because it should cause a distinct value "fair" in the result set.  However, "Fair" will not show for any other month if I group by "Date".

What I've done to solve the problem seems a bit more difficult than necessary, but I'm having trouble figuring out what would be easier. I want to return the sum "Dollars" for all the distinct "Quality" results for the most recent two "Dates" from this table.

I've done the following:

```
declare @currdt date = '02/28/2015'
declare @prevdt date = DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@currdt),0)) --last day of month prior
declare @dates table (date1 date);

insert into @dates (date1) values (@currdt), (@prevdt);

with qualities (quality, date) as
( 
    select distinct quality, date1
    from mytableA
    join (select * from @dates) a on 1=1
),
history (ID, Quality, Add_Date, Dollars)
(
    select ID, Quality, Add_Date, Dollars
    from mytableA
    where Add_Date <= @currdt
    and Add_Date >= @prevdt
)
select 
    q.quality, q.date, sum(h.Dollars)
from 
    qualities q
left join 
    history h on h.quality = q.quality and h.date = q.date
group by 
    q.quality, q.date
```

The desired result based on the table shown above should be as follows:

```
Quality  | Date     | Dollars
------------------------------
Fair     | 02/28/15 | 1
Good     | 02/28/15 | 1
Better   | 02/28/15 | 2
Best     | 02/28/15 | 3
Fair     | 01/31/15 | 0
Good     | 01/31/15 | 1
Better   | 01/31/15 | 2
Best     | 01/31/15 | 3
```

I should have listed some repetitive qualities in a given month to make the sums more interesting, but hopefully this is clear.

Comment: Good description but I'm still a bit confused - could you post your desired result set as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal just is to reduce the query length then this should be equivalent to what you have now (plus it outputs all qualities for both dates):

```
declare @currdt date = '02/28/2015'
declare @prevdt date = DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@currdt),0)) --last day of month prior

select a.quality, a.date, sum(isnull(b.Dollars,0)) as dollars
from (select quality, d.date from mytableA, (VALUES (@currdt), (@prevdt)) AS d(date) group by Quality, d.date) a
left join mytableA b on a.Date = b.date and a.Quality = b.Quality
group by a.quality, a.date
order by 2 desc, 3 asc
```

With your sample data this would output:

```
quality date        dollars
Fair    2015-02-28  1
Good    2015-02-28  1
Better  2015-02-28  2
Best    2015-02-28  3
Fair    2015-01-31  0
Good    2015-01-31  1
Better  2015-01-31  2
Best    2015-01-31  3
```

If you want to maintain the order for quality (`fair -> good -> better -> best`) you can do this:

```
select a.quality, a.date, sum(isnull(b.Dollars,0)) as sum
from (select quality, sort, date from 
    (values (1, 'Fair'), (2, 'Good'), (3, 'Better'), (4, 'Best')) as q(sort, quality), 
    (values (@currdt), (@prevdt)) as d(date) group by q.quality, d.date, sort) a
left join mytableA b on a.Date = b.date and a.Quality = b.Quality
group by a.quality, a.date, sort
order by date desc, sort
```

Comment: Didn't realize "values" could be used in that fashion!  Definitely more concise and doesn't require a table variable to join the dates to the distinct quality values, which is what I was after.  I had originally tried to cross apply the dates to the distinct quality values, but I couldn't get the syntax correct.

Comment: @IanJoyce Yes, the _table value constructor_ as it's called that were introduced with SQL Server 2008 can be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I would do it if I didn't have another table that listed the qualities:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,RateableItemID INT
    ,Quality VARCHAR(15)
    ,Date DATE
    ,Dollars MONEY
)
INSERT INTO @Table
(
    RateableItemID 
    ,Quality 
    ,Date 
    ,Dollars 
)
VALUES
(1       ,'Good'    , '02/28/15' , 1 )
,(2       ,'Better'  , '02/28/15' , 2 )
,(3       ,'Best'    , '02/28/15' , 3 )
,(4       ,'Fair'   , '02/28/15' , 1 )
,(1       ,'Good'    , '01/31/15' , 1 )
,(2       ,'Better'  , '01/31/15' , 2 )
,(3       ,'Best'    , '01/31/15' , 3 )
,(1       ,'Good'    , '12/31/15' , 1 )
,(3       ,'Best'    , '12/31/15' , 3 )

SELECT 
    TwoMostRecentDates.Date
    ,Qualities.Quality
    ,ISNULL(SUM(Details.Dollars),0) AS DollarsForThisDateAndQuality
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 
        Date
    FROM
        @Table 
    ORDER BY Date DESC
) TwoMostRecentDates
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Quality
    FROM @Table
) Qualities
LEFT JOIN
    @Table Details
    ON TwoMostRecentDates.Date = Details.Date
    AND Qualities.Quality = Details.Quality
GROUP BY
    TwoMostRecentDates.Date
    ,Qualities.Quality
ORDER BY
    TwoMostRecentDates.Date
    ,CASE
        Qualities.Quality
        WHEN 'Best' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Better' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Good' THEN 3
        WHEN 'Fair' THEN 4
    END
```

It is my opinion that for all code, readability trumps character count.